# simple javascript loop to sum grid column

Tags: javascript, loops

I need to create a javascript loop that will add the values from a each row (rowCount) of a table column and output the total (QT_BOX * rowCount = prodQty).  The rowCountupdates fine, but the prodQty always returns a value of 50.  I think I must be overlooking something, but can't seem tot find it...

```
function updateCounters(){
    var gridObject = document.BoxesGrid.getGridObject();
    var rowCount = gridObject.getRowCount();
    for(var i=0; i <= rowCount; i++){
        var prodQty = gridObject.getCellValueByName(i, "QT_BOX");
        document.getElementById("QT_READ").value =prodQty;
        document.getElementById("QT_BOXES").value = rowCount;
    }       
}
```

Answer (score 0):

In your FOR loop you update the "QT_READ" with the current row's prodQty (or QT_BOX) .. but it is never added to the previous amount, so you will always have your last row's prodQty!

here is what it might look like:

```
function updateCounters(){
    var gridObject = document.BoxesGrid.getGridObject();
    var rowCount = gridObject.getRowCount();
    for(var i=0; i <= rowCount; i++){
        var prodQty = gridObject.getCellValueByName(i, "QT_BOX");
        var total = document.getElementById("QT_READ").value;
        document.getElementById("QT_READ").value = prodQty + total;
        document.getElementById("QT_BOXES").value = rowCount;
    }       
}
```

Comment: Ah. That makes sense. I'm not sure how I would add these though. As you can probably tell, I am very new to javascript.  I'm assuming that I would change this line ----  var prodQty = gridObject.getCellValueByName(i, "QT_BOX");----    I'm just not really sure where the total accumulated value is stored and how to retrireve/display it.

Comment: well you might want to change this line to do this:
var prodQty = gridObject.getCellValueByName(i, "QT_BOX");
var total = document.getElementById("QT_READ").value;
document.getElementById("QT_READ").value = total + prodQty;

Answer (score 0):

I don't know what "BoxesGrid" is. But by your code I see that you are setting up the "QT_BOXES" at the same value "rowCount" in every repetition in the loop. So I guess that BoxesGrid is a grid with 50 rows that's why you get allways a total of 50.

You should sum every value in the "for" clause and then set the "QT_BOXES" outside the "for" clause.

```
function updateCounters(){
    var gridObject = document.BoxesGrid.getGridObject();
    var rowCount = gridObject.getRowCount();
    var tot = 0;
    for(var i=0; i <= rowCount; i++){
        var prodQty = gridObject.getCellValueByName(i, "QT_BOX");
        document.getElementById("QT_READ").value =prodQty;
        tot += prodQty;
    }       
    document.getElementById("QT_BOXES").value = tot;
}
```

Comment: Thank you for your help.  in your example, tot returns a string with all of the field values in the loop.  What I need to do is add all the values instead of display them though.